# Bower: Installing legacy bootstrap (2.3.2) with bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower

I have an open source webapp using bootstrap 2.3.2 and which Currently I can't move to bootstrap 3 (completely different grid system) - I'm trying to move the webapp to use bower to handle dependencies but `bower install bootstrap#2.3.2` fetches something that looks as the raw code repo not built, for example no css folder, just the seperate `less` files, no one minified `bootstrap.min.js` but multiple different plugins (not concatenated) etc..

Is this fixable? should I install differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I ended up with: forked bootstrap repo, cleaned up(other branches etc..) `git reset --hard` to the v2.3.2 tag - checked it into another branch and pushe it to github. more cleanup (removing the old master branch, higher tags). run the build processes and setup an "updated" dist folder for the v2.3.2 tag. changed the bower package and published it as bootstrap2.3.2 package.

Now I (and everyone else) can install with bower install from this repo. The results are [here](https://github.com/alonisser/bower-bootstrap-2.3.2-legacy) if someone want to use it.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to compile Bootstrap 2.3.2 as well, but I'm facing an error message when executing "Grunt" command. It says "A valid Gruntfile could not be found." I think it means GruntFile.JS file, which is not part of this repository. Can you help me with that missing file?

Comment: There is no gruntfile and therefor no grunt.. this build with MAKE.. you can alsoo use the my bower 2.3.2 fork and just "bower install bootstrap2.3.2"

Answer (score 3):

You are doing everything correct.  Take a look at the `README` for `v2.3.2` on [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v2.3.2)

> Bootstrap includes a makefile with convenient methods for working with
>   the framework. Before getting started, be sure to install the
>   necessary local dependencies:
>
> $ npm install When completed, you'll be able to run the various make
>   commands provided:
>
> build - make
>
> Runs the recess compiler to rebuild the /less files and compiles the
>   docs. Requires recess and uglify-js.
>
> test - make test
>
> Runs jshint and qunit tests headlessly in phantomjs (used for ci).
>   Depends on having phantomjs installed.
>
> watch - make watch

Comment: I know I can build it myself. but I don't like adding steps (and tooling) to a simple project, while my main motivation for moving to bower is removing setup complexity to allow more developer ob board.. sigh.. looks like I'll have to vendor it into the project

Comment: Could always raise the issue on Github.  Not sure why the older builds don't have a `dist` folder.

Comment: I know it sucks - but this really is the only answer here.

Comment: Raised a github issue about this, lets see what the response would be

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this and was basically setting up my own fork of Bootstrap 2.3.2 (before I noticed your answer). As I dove in, I noticed that Bootstrap 2.3.2 actually **does** come with pre-built assets you can use in your project. While it's not as obvious as the `dist/` directory in Bootstrap 3, you can find the location of the prebuilt assets in [the project's bower.json](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v2.3.2/bower.json#L4):

```
"main": ["./docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js", "./docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css"],
```

So there you go. Add `{"bootstrap": "~2.3.2"}` to your `bower.json` dependencies like you normally would, then use it like this:

```
<link href="bower_components/bootstrap/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/docs/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

No build step required.