# Installing bootstrap using bower did not provide any css file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bower, twitter-bootstrap-2

I used the usual

> bower install bootstrap#2.3.2

This worked fine and created a bootstrap folder inside bower_components. however this did not provide me with a .css file which i would include in my index.html

the Folder structure looks like this:

```
myApp/
  bower_components/
    bootstrap/
      docs/
      img/
      js/
      less/
      bower.json
      composer.json
      Makefile
      package.json
      ...some more files
```

All i really wanted was a simple css file to use in my project. I searched around on stackoverflow and internet. Didn't find any directions as to how to use this folder to get my css file. The closet I found was this link: [Bower: Installing legacy bootstrap (2.3.2) with bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376440/bower-installing-legacy-bootstrap-2-3-2-with-bower) which still doesn't say where to get the css file from.

What are the steps I have to take